# Can I use value of a variable to name a new variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this case, I'm trying to create variable history0 using the value from accountno

```
accountno = 0
history<accountno> = 'dep 100$'
```

Comment: Use lists or dictionaries, you do **not** want dynamic variable names.

Comment: This was my first major stumbling block when starting to work with Python. How do I create dynamic variable names for `var_A0, var_A1,..., var_An` containing values  `val_A0, val_A1,...,val_An`? Answer: You don't. Store them in a list `list_A=[val_A0, val_A1,...val_An]` and retrieve the number of each value within the list with `for i, val_A in enumerate(list_A):`. Need to combine variables `var_A0,...,var_An` with their corresponding counterparts  `var_B0,...,var_Bn`? Zip the two lists: `for val_A, val_B in zip(list_A, list_B):`.